# Sorting by custom SQL in JpaRepository Sort method

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to express the below query using an JPA query method?

```
  @Query(
      value =
          "SELECT a FROM #{#entityName} a"
              + "LEFT JOIN Other o ON a.otherId = o.id"
              + "ORDER BY CASE WHEN o.foo = 'A' then 1"
              + "              WHEN o.foo = 'S' then 2"
              + "              WHEN o.foo = 'D' then 3"
              + "              ELSE 4"
              + "         END, a.createdDate DESC NULLS LAST")
  List<T> findAllCustomSorted();
```

So something like this query method

```
List<T> findAll(Sort sort);
```

Called something like this

```
String fooProperty = "CASE WHEN o.foo = 'A' then 1"
                        + "WHEN o.foo = 'S' then 2"
                        + "WHEN o.foo = 'D' then 3"
                        + "ELSE 4"
                    + END;
String dateProperty = "createdDate";
repo.findAll(
    new Sort(
        new Order(Direction.ASC, fooProperty, NullHandling.NULLS_LAST),
        new Order(Direction.DESC, dateProperty, NullHandling.NULLS_LAST)));
```

Now this doesn't work.

But I found something called `JpaSort.unsafe()` and `JpaPath` so wondering if what I'm trying to do is possible before I go down the rabbit hole.

Comment: You can't use Sort this way. What about sorting it after you got the list, using .stream().map().sorted()?

Comment: I prefer doing sorting in the database. At some point paging will be enabled

Comment: That's not possible because sort needs a property path. What if you save the sort key (1,2,3,4) on the table as extra column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sort if you have a property name which is comparable. Try changing the select query you use to include the sorting key as another column:

```
@Query(
  value =
      "SELECT a, CASE WHEN o.foo = 'A' then 1"
          + "              WHEN o.foo = 'S' then 2"
          + "              WHEN o.foo = 'D' then 3"
          + "              ELSE 4"
          + "         END sort FROM #{#entityName} a"
          + "LEFT JOIN Other o ON a.otherId = o.id"
          + "ORDER BY a.createdDate DESC NULLS LAST")
List<T> findAllCustomSorted();
```

This means that your result will have two columns - a and its sort key. Now you could use "sort" as your sort by property by using:

```
repo.findAll(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "sort"));
```

Comment: That could work. But I really wanted it to not rely on a @Query as they're not that refactor friendly

Comment: The @Query is your best option to get complex selects from the DB. Let it do the heavy lifting. It’s less likely the sql will need to be refactored than any code, though.